# Git: How to edit old commit with multiple descendant branches?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history

My git repo's history looked like:

```
* (topic2) commit_11
* (topic1) commit_10
* commit_9
* commit_8
* (HEAD, master) commit_7
* commit_6
* commit_5
* commit_4 <- I wanted to edit this commit.
* commit_3
```

So I did

```
git rebase -i commit_3
```

and replace `pick` by `edit` for commit_4 in editor.
I corrected some typos in variable names and then

```
git add .
git commit --amend
(rename commit)
git rebase --continue
```

And now history looks like:

```
* (HEAD, master) commit_7.1
* commit_6.1
* commit_5.1
* commit_4.1 <- Edited commit.
| * (topic2) commit_11
| * (topic1) commit_10
| * commit_9
| * commit_8
| * commit_7
| * commit_6
| * commit_5
| * commit_4 <- Original commit.
|/
* commit_3
```

I want to make my history straight and clean like previous. I try the way that I successfully used multiple times before

```
git checkout topic1
git rebase master
```

But it ends up with conflicts when applying first patch. I resolved them manually. But when I try `git rebase --continue`, it tells me "Nothing to commit".

How to deal with the problem and why it has arisen?

Comment: i think you're abusing versioning a little bit. if you made a mistake in commit_4, fix it in a new commit, and if you need that fix in different branches, cherry-pick it into other branches

Comment: If none of these are pushed, it's not unreasonable to do.

Comment: What branch was the current during this rebase? I guess if you make reediting in master and then rebase topic* on master, the history will be linear.

Comment: @Netch, if I understand you right, my case is just like you say. `(HEAD, master)` before edit. `git rebase master` for topic1

Comment: Embrace nonlinear version history and your problem will magically go away. git is not svn.

Comment: @Max, I use linear history to simplify control over branches. Because I am not much proficient in git.

Comment: @Max The issue is not the "nonlinear history". The issue is, the edits made during the rebase will only appear on the branch the rebase is performed at. Other branches will have unedited versions. That is, the OP says that they fixed some typos in an older commit. Now, the fixed version will appear only on the `master` branch (since that is the branch the rebase was performed on), but it won't appear on other branches like `topic1`, `topic2`, etc. It is supposed to appear on other branches as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I took the liberty of modifying your diagram to indicate that when you rebase, *all* the commits change, even if the contents don't.  Your new set of commits will have different shas than the originals.)

The simplest solution here is use `--onto`.  Have a look at this link, starting at the text "Here is how you would transplant a topic branch":  [git rebase](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html)

So in your case, it would be:

```
git rebase --onto commit_7.1 commit_7 topic1
```

In other words, take the commits from *after* commit_7 until (including) topic1, and transplant them onto commit_7.1.

You may still get merge failures that you have to manually fix, though.

I recommend that when you do this, you create an extra branch on the topic1 commit.  Call it topic1old or something.  That'll make it easier to go back in case the rebase doesn't go right; you can just hard reset your topic1 back to that commit.

**EDIT**: Why didn't simple `git rebase master` work?

If you don't tell it otherwise, git rebase assumes that you're rebasing against your upstream branch.

But as you see from the way I modified the diagram, topic1 and master don't have much in common anymore.  If you do a simple rebase onto master, topic1 will try to rebase all of your commits onto all of the commits on master.  Which means you'll get something like:

- (topic1) commit_10
- commit_9
- commit_8
- commit_7
- commit_6
- commit_5
- commit_4
- (HEAD, master) commit_7.1
- commit_6.1
- commit_5.1
- commit_4.1 <- Edited commit.
- commit_3

Now Git is smart about not duplicating commits that are already present.  Obviously if you make changes X, Y, and Z, and then a later commit makes those again, Git just omits the later commit since those changes are already present.

But what throws a wrench into things is your change to commit 4.  The result is that all of the commits after that are committing onto a different set of code.  This leaves the potential necessity for a lot of merging.

Using --onto fixes this because it allows you to use a different base.  You're saying: "I don't care about commit_4 (because I changed it) nor about commit_5, _6, and _7 (because I've already merged them, and they're essentially the same as in my topic branch).  So start from commit_8 on, rebasing just those changes on top of the stuff I've already dealt with."

Comment: Kyralessa, your solution did the job. But can anyone explain why simple `git rebase master` does not work this time?

Comment: Kyralessa, thanks for clarifying. I guess that success of `git rebase master` depends on what changes was made to commit_4.